# Scan Open ports by Ping Scan method

Tags: networking, tcp, port, icmp

During online course I came across the term "Ping Scan" in which we sends ICMP packets to target IP address.
It made me confuse because we know every machine has random IP address assigned by Router.
So how it is possible to scan ports of specific IP.

Comment: IP addresses are certainly not random, and are not necessarily assigned by routers, but ICMP doesn't have ports, so it can't tell you whether a port is open. Unclear what you're really asking.

Answer (score -1):

YOu will scna by nmap. Or if you don't know how to use nmap use https://nmap.online